# Javascript - Add Dynamic Query Paramter to Current URL Without Reload

Tags: javascript, search, dynamic, parameters

**Background:** I have little knowledge of javascript, only html and css.

**My Problem:** I have a dynamic table on my webpage (WPDataTables) that includes a global search and then column specific search.  My users can type into these searches and the content will dynamically update. My problem is the URL does not update to include search parameters so we cannot copy and send URL's to other people that include specific search results.

WpDataTables currently has the following keys to pre filter the table:

- Global: ?wdt_search=filtervalue
- Column: ?wdt_column_filter[ColumnName]=filtervalue

This is great but my users aren't savvy enough to create their own URL strings and there are a large number of possible filters so pre-creating each one is not an option.

**Currently:** I am close to getting a solution, I think, with the following:

```
<body>
  <button onclick="updateURL();">Update</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function updateURL() {
      if (history.pushState) {
          var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?para=hello';
          window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Ideally, with this the user will simply click the Update button to update the URL with the current search parameters. The problem is ?para=hello is just a hard coded parameter and I can't figure out how to get it to be dynamic and change with the users searching/filtering.

My website: http://imsched.com/sailings

Comment: So append whatever value what there...Read the form fields and build the querystring

Comment: I'm new to Javascript and have no idea how to correctly do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query string can't be updated without reloading the page. If you want to track those updates in the url so they are shareable, and still have them affect your filters you could use the hash instead. The hash can be easily read and you can update it without reloading the page.

```
// to read
window.location.hash

// to update
window.location.hash = 'param=value&param=value'
```

If you had a url like this `http://url.com#1=one&2=two&3=three`, you could do the following:

```
var filters = window.location.hash.split('&')
// filters now = ['1=one', '2=two', '3=three']
// so you can make easy use of those
```

---

### Update

If you need to update the query string and don't mind that it reloads the page each time, you can manipulate it via `window.location.search`

```
// to read
window.location.search

// to update (will reload the page)
window.location.search = window.location.search + '&your_stuff=here'
```

A function that could build your query string from your filter fields could look like this:

```
function buildQuery() {
  var inputs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-filter'))

  return inputs.reduce(function(str, el, i) {
    return str + (i > 0 ? '&' : '') + el.name + '=' + el.value  
  }, '')
}
```

Example fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rbvmrfh3/2/)

Comment: This was over my head a little bit but I am Googling to try and understand.  I am working with the systems current search parameters of Global: ?wdt_search=filtervalue and Column Only: ?wdt_column_filter[ColumnName]=filtervalue and can't manipulate how that works so I don't believe I can use the hash.  The way I have it I am able to click the Update URL button and the URL will display a parameter based on the script I have above I just didn't know if there was a way to combine the ?para=hello with the wdt_column_filter and wdt_search like above.

Thank you for your time and answers.

Comment: If you're using the query string server-side to generate all of the html, then the hash won't work for you. If you're filtering stuff on the client then you can still use the hash. You would just read from both the query (window.location.search) and the hash to do your client-side filtering.

Comment: Thank you for the update.  Would you be able to show me what the function that I will include might look like in my case?  I'm not sure how to write that.

Comment: It depends on what exactly you're working with, but I updated the answer to point you in a direction for building a query string from inputs on the page.

Comment: Thank you, still trying to get it working but I appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use HTML5 History Manipulation:
https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/

It's more commom with AngularJS, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the above solution didn't work for me you can try this:

```js
window.location.pathname.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/, "");
```